# combine multiple TextViews in a TablerRow

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

i want to create a tablelayout within the code.
Every n-th row should be a Headline with only one textview. The other rows should contain 3 textviews. All first, second and third views should be the same width of course.

my problem now is that the width of the first column is set by the broadest texview which is the headline, but that's way to big for the first views of the other rows. so i would like to combine the cells of the row, where the headline is located, so it can span over the whole row. and the other cells should be the size of the broadest text.

this is how it should look

```
______________________________
|Long Title__________________|
|x___|YYYY_____|ZZZ__________|
|XXX_|YYYYYYYYY|ZZZZ_________|
|xxxx|YYYYY____|ZZZ__________|
|xxx_|YY_______|Z____________|
|Long Title__________________|
|x___|YYYY_____|ZZZ__________|
|XXX_|YYYYYYYYY|ZZZZ_________|
|xxxx|YYYYY____|ZZZ__________|
|xxx_|YY_______|Z____________|
```

this is how it looks atm

```
______________________________
|Long Title__________________|
|x_________|YYYY_____|ZZZ____|
|XXX_______|YYYYYYYYY|ZZZZ___|
|xxxx______|YYYYY____|ZZZ____|
|xxx_______|YY_______|Z______|
|Long Title__________________|
|x_________|YYYY_____|ZZZ____|
|XXX_______|YYYYYYYYY|ZZZZ___|
|xxxx______|YYYYY____|ZZZ____|
|xxx_______|YY_______|Z______|
```

would be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code can help. Just add another Linear Layout block to have 3 rows.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/Textviewtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="90dp"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Textviewtitle"
     android:layout_below="@+id/Textviewtitle"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

 <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/Textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" />
 <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/Textview2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" />
 <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/Textview3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" />



 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/Textview4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" />
 <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/Textview5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" />
 <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/Textview6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" />
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Use the following links for more reference on aligning. Once you add the 3rd Linear Layout block , with weight 1, it will align perfectly.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Repeating the same, you can get another 3 block row.

Please see the edit. you can use something like this

Comment: the problem with linear layout is the the first textviews arent the same width.

Comment: i tried in my eclipse and the graphic layout seems perfectly fine. Can you please point out where you are saying the problem is?

Comment: if you use the weights, they wil perfectly be the same width. You use weights between the textviews in a block to maintain the length, and between linear layouts stacked one upon the other to maintain the height.

Comment: i think you misunderstood. not the textviews in a row should be the same width, but the textviews within the same column. your example only works because you are useint the same string all the time.

Comment: alri8. in tht case. replace the sub linear layouts vertical. add each text view as a column. and replace the parent linear layout horizontal. get it.? Please see the edit in few minutes.

Comment: you got my point? please let me know if am not explanatory enuf.